# GetKeyboardLayout returns strange layout

Tags: c++, keyboard

GetKeyboardLayout(0) seems to have decided my thread is using some kind of mixture of `LANG_GERMAN`, `SUBLANG_GERMAN`, `LANG_ENGLISH` and `SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US`. I've tried putting this in a new project, but the problem persists... Here's the code I've used to test it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <kbd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Keyboard Layout ID: " << GetKeyboardLayout(0) << "\n";
    std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

That keeps returning `04070409` though which I don't think should be possible. (Or is it? If yes how would I construct this with [`MAKELANGID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?) This maps to the mixture of languages above according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I've tried using [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `MAKELANGID(LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_GERMAN_AUSTRIAN)` but I just get a standard `LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH` (04090409) layout. Have I just read the docs wrong and messed up something, or what's happening here? I'm out of ideas...

Comment: It is *very* unclear what problem you are trying to solve.  Other than that it is pretty likely you should not be solving it.  Switching keyboard layouts should be left entirely up to the user, very simple to do with the language bar.

Comment: The problem is that ToUnicodeEx requires a keyboard layout, which I'm having trouble getting. I'm not trying to force the user into a layout

Comment: No, GetKeyboardLayout() is what you use.  With the further constraint that it is a process-specific value and you cannot obtain the active keyboard layout for another process.  Which makes using ToUnicodeEx in a low-level keyboard hook a lost cause.  Still very much an XY question.

Comment: Ok, but even if it wouldn't work I'd still be interested in why it returns what it does. Just for future reference ;) So if anyone has any ideas what this means I'd be glad to know.

Comment: If anyone comes across this, it is actually possible to get the KeyLayout of another process. I'm using toUnicodeEx and it works perfectly fine :) `GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation for [GetKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm surprised you missed it, since it is the documentation for the function return value.

> **Return value**
>
> Type: **HKL**
>
> The return value is the input locale identifier for the thread. The
>   low word contains a [Language Identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the input language and the
>   high word contains a device handle to the physical layout of the
>   keyboard.

`04070409` is therefore the layout for the US-English language on a physical German keyboard.

You cannot make this with `MAKELANGID` because `MAKELANGID` creates language IDs, but this is a `HKL` (keyboard layout handle).

It's not clear why you care about the handle's numeric value. The nature of handles is that they are supposed to be opaque.

Comment: Well, that doesn't help me seeing as AFAIK I'm using a German layout on a German keyboard. Since when does the US-English layout contain `äöü` etc?

Comment: It's not the US-English layout. It's the US-English language. The system will interpret your typing as intended for the English language.

Comment: Oh right. Well why is `LoadKeyboardLayout` refusing to get me a German layout then? EDIT: I probably don't need to care seeing as I can just use the layout returned by `GetKeyboardLayout` but I'd still like to know ;)